# Weird noise on rendered objects - OpenGL

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, shader, render

To be more specific, here's the screenshot:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_o-Ym0jhIqmY2JJNmhSeGpyanM/edit?usp=sharing

After debugging for about 3 days, I really have no idea. Those black lines and strange fractal black segments just drive me nuts. The geometries are rendered by forward rendering, blending layer by layer for each light I add.

My first guess was downloading the newest graphics card driver (I'm using GTX 660m), but that didn't solve it. Can VSync be a possible issue here? (I'm rendering in a window rather on full screen mode) Or what is the most possible point to cause this kind of trouble?

My code is like this:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glDepthMask(false);
glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL);

/*loop here*/   
/*draw for each light I had*/   

glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glDepthMask(true);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

Comment: Looks like z-fighting issues. Are there multiple overlapped mesh surfaces?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's not. The floor is even made up with just two triangles. And as I move forward, back, left and right (i.e., my camera), the issue remains. If I turned, no matter which axis, this effect just disappeared. But it still occur at some specific angle, almost randomly, and cause the screen to flicker at some times.

Comment: Can you post your shader code?

Comment: It's about ten thousand lines... but here is the render part: 
http://codepad.org/LMNM6VQy

Comment: A ten thousand line shader? How? A forward rendered shader with results such as the ones you posted should be less than 20 lines, vert and frag shader combined...

Comment: Ok, I got it! But still not too short...
Seems like maybe it's my point lights causing the problem, here is the glsl code that I use to render the scene:
[link](http://codepad.org/2fSDxehl) and [link](http://codepad.org/9r00GJzg)

Comment: Here is the FWD_AMBIENT shader that I used in the first post of codepad: http://codepad.org/C34Tl6Q1

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've noticed looking at your lighting vertex shader code:

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
    normal0 = (normalMatrix * vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
    modelViewPos0 = (modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1)).xyz;
}
```

You are applying the projection matrix directly to the vertex position, which I'm assuming is in object space.

Try setting it to:

```
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

And we can work from there.

Comment: While I pass in the projectionMatrix, it has already done the projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix part, but I tried your suggestion anyway and discovered a even strange result that confused me... though I've done twice * modelViewMatrix that just don't make sense...
ORIGINAL: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_o-Ym0jhIqmNXhINEkxd1d6ZWs/edit
MODIFIED: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_o-Ym0jhIqmMFpQUTZmZXJjT2M/edit

Comment: The MVP transform you do during your ambient pass does not persist to the lighting passes if that is what you are talking about. Or are you transforming the vertices on the CPU and then re-buffering them each frame (which I would not recommend doing)?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the render of just the ambient pass? And then a screenshot of a single light pass, with not ambient?

Comment: Ahh, the naming of my ambient pass was wrong, now I correct it to projectionMatrix. On CPU side, there's only matrix stuff.
AMBIENT PASS(I emphasize the ambient lighting 5X. It is perfectly normal): https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_o-Ym0jhIqmX2xlUTRIUUIyNk0/edit
SINGLE LIGHT(With ambient light, because I'm depending on the depth value it created. Back to the issue. QAQ):https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_o-Ym0jhIqmQjNQbEd2MENqRG8/edit

Comment: Oh my god, seems the problem is about my camera matrix or perspective matrix. I randomly change some negative values to positive and things just normal as usual, still don't know why...

Comment: Things turn out that it is wrong, all my matrices were correct, so, I'm back to the problem... (what I forget to mention in my previous comment is all my objects there become transparent)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is slightly speculative, but based on the symptoms, and the code you posted, I suspect a precision problem. The rendering code you linked, looks like this in a shortened form:

```
useShader(FWD_AMBIENT);
part.render();

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL);
for (Light light : lights) {
    useShader(light.getShaderType());
    part.render();
}
```

So you're rendering the same thing multiple times, with different shaders, and rely on the resulting pixels to end up with the same depth value (depth comparison function is `GL_EQUAL`). This is not a safe assumption. Quote from the GLSL spec:

> In this section, variance refers to the possibility of getting different values from the same expression in different programs.  For example, say two vertex shaders, in different programs, each set gl_Position with the same expression in both shaders, and the input values into that expression are the same when both shaders run.  It is possible, due to independent compilation of the two shaders, that the values assigned to gl_Position are not exactly the same when the two shaders run.  In this example, this can cause problems with alignment of geometry in a multi-pass algorithm.

I copied the whole paragraph because the example they are using sounds like an exact description of what you are doing.

To prevent this from happening, you can declare your `out` variables as `invariant`. In each of your vertex shaders that you use for the multi-pass rendering, add this line:

```
invariant gl_Position;
```

This guarantees that the outputs are identical if all the inputs are the same. To meet this condition, you should also make sure that you pass exactly the same transformation matrix into both shaders, and of course use the same vertex coordinates.

Comment: I use 4 shaders in this program, and I add "invariant gl_Position" on the global space for every shader, but it didn't work... But I think I'm passing different transformation matrix into the shader because I break the scene into parts (different objects), and for each part, they're transformed by their own matrix (they are moving), and rendered by all lights. In each rendering pass, transformation matrix remains the same, but between parts, they vary.

Comment: As long as the transformation matrices are identical for each part across the multiple passes, you should be fine.

Comment: I tried comment out all my code execpt a single light and a plane, they should have the same translation matrix, in theory. But the result is the same. Also, the odd lines seem to have the orientation of the ground triangles.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_o-Ym0jhIqmS3NiVHlrWEM2S0E/edit